# Comparison of data depending upon the format

Tags: vba, excel

I needed to compare data from two databases. So, I populated the data into an excel sheet and used the following VBA code for the comparision.

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)

  Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer 
  Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String 
  Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long 
  Dim row As Long, col As Integer 

  Set report = Workbooks.Add 

  With ws1.UsedRange 
    ws1row = .Rows.Count 
    ws1col = .Columns.Count 
  End With 

  With ws2.UsedRange 
    ws2row = .Rows.Count 
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
  End With

  maxrow = ws1row 
  maxcol = ws1col 
  If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row 
  If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col 

  difference = 0 

  For col = 1 To maxcol 
    For row = 1 To maxrow 
      colval1 = "" 
      colval2 = "" 
      colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula 
      colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula 
      If colval1 <> colval2 Then 
        difference = difference + 1 
        Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2 
        Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255 
        Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2 
        Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True 
      End If 
    Next row 
  Next col 

  Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25 
  report.Saved = True 

  If difference = 0 Then 
    report.Close False 
  End If 
  Set report = Nothing 
  MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, _
         "Comparing Two       Worksheets" 
End Sub
```

Here Cell wise comparison is done. Now, I needed to compare depending upon the data type. Like if it a number, then I need to check till two decimals.  Could you help me out in incorporating this requirement.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question but believe the function `VarType` may meet your need.

Comment: You can try e.g. `IsNumeric(colval1)` and switch the equivalence test based on the result. For 2-decimal precision on numerics, `Round(colval1,2)` might do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code has solved my purpose. @andy Thanks a lot. Your comments helped in solving my problem.

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
Dim report As Workbook, difference As Long
Dim row As Long, col As Integer
Dim lvalue As Boolean
Set report = Workbooks.Add
With ws1.UsedRange
ws1row = .Rows.Count
ws1col = .Columns.Count
End With
With ws2.UsedRange
ws2row = .Rows.Count
ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With
maxrow = ws1row
maxcol = ws1col
If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col
difference = 0
For col = 1 To maxcol
  For row = 1 To maxrow
  colval1 = ""
  colval2 = ""
  colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
  colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula

  If IsNumeric(colval1) Or IsNumeric(colval2) Then

     If Round(Val(colval1), 2) <> Round(Val(colval2), 2) Then
        difference = difference + 1
        Cells(row, col).Formula = "DIFF " & colval1 & "<> " & colval2
        Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
        Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
     End If

  Else
     If colval1 <> colval2 Then
        difference = difference + 1
        Cells(row, col).Formula = "DIFF " & colval1 & "<> " & colval2
        Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
        Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
        Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
     End If
  End If
 Next row
 Next col
 Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
 report.Saved = True
 If difference = 0 Then
 report.Close False
 End If
 Set report = Nothing
 MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two    Worksheets"
 End Sub
```